# (Warning) IP address 'XXX.XXX.XX.XXX' could not be resolved: Name or service not known

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I Use Mariadb-10.3 at 127.0.0.1:3310. The sites are working correctly, everything is fine. But I noticed these connections in the logs:

```
200812 21:16:31 [Warning] IP address '195.54.167.225' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
200813  1:44:22 [Warning] IP address '177.156.63.4' has been resolved to the host name '177.156.63.4.dynamic.adsl.gvt.net.br', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
200813  3:03:27 [Warning] IP address '51.103.146.73' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
200813  3:24:40 [Warning] IP address '20.52.50.38' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
200813 15:01:29 [Note] Hostname 'worker-13.sfj.censys-scanner.com' does not resolve to '192.35.168.220'.
200813 15:01:29 [Note] Hostname 'worker-13.sfj.censys-scanner.com' has the following IP addresses:
200813 15:01:29 [Note]  - 192.35.168.208

200813 18:14:01 [Warning] IP address '170.130.187.30' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
200813 21:14:05 [Warning] IP address '64.227.86.82' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
200813 21:39:55 [Note] Hostname '186-210-095-134.xd-dynamic.algarnetsuper.com.br' does not resolve to '186.210.95.134'.
200813 21:39:55 [Note] Hostname '186-210-095-134.xd-dynamic.algarnetsuper.com.br' has the following IP addresses:
200813 21:39:55 [Note]  - 195.85.231.19

200813 23:11:43 [Warning] IP address '92.63.194.76' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
200814  1:17:00 [Warning] IP address '79.152.33.82' has been resolved to the host name '82.red-79-152-33.dynamicip.rima-tde.net', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
200814 13:18:19 [Warning] IP address '118.193.28.58' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
200814 18:47:42 [Note] Hostname '3c2e01.rederatural.com' does not resolve to '104.140.188.10'.
200814 18:47:42 [Note] Hostname '3c2e01.rederatural.com' has the following IP addresses:
200814 18:47:42 [Note]  - 212.32.237.101

200814 20:25:51 [Note] Hostname '683b217.rederatural.com' does not resolve to '104.140.188.6'.
200814 20:25:51 [Note] Hostname '683b217.rederatural.com' has the following IP addresses:
200814 20:25:51 [Note]  - 212.32.237.90

200814 22:43:46 [Note] Hostname 'zg-0708b-125.stretchoid.com' does not resolve to '192.241.238.224'.
200814 22:43:46 [Note] Hostname 'zg-0708b-125.stretchoid.com' has the following IP addresses:
200814 22:43:46 [Note]  - 178.210.89.119

200814 23:08:48 [Note] Hostname 'zg-0708a-49.stretchoid.com' does not resolve to '192.241.212.195'.
200814 23:08:48 [Note] Hostname 'zg-0708a-49.stretchoid.com' has the following IP addresses:
200814 23:08:48 [Note]  - 178.210.89.119

200814 23:40:20 [Warning] IP address '80.82.78.85' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
200815  2:01:33 [Warning] IP address '183.136.225.44' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
```

After that, the mysql server is disabled and i have to restart it. Can you tell me what this is? Attempted hacking or something else?

I read it somewhere and in /etc/my.cnf added `skip_name_resolve = 1`. Helps?

Comment: why is your sql service reachable by internet?

Comment: @rickjames i wrote  service not server, read more precisely?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each incoming connection, MariaDB is attempting to do a DNS lookup.  As you wrote in the question, adding `skip-name-resolve = on` to `/etc/my.cnf` will prevent the lookup.

The fact that you are even getting these connection attempts means your DB is exposed to the Internet.  It would be highly recommended not to allow public access to that port, e.g. limit to loopback interface and/or use the firewall to only allow whitelisted IPs.